# XML Formatting from Kotlin class

Tags: xml, kotlin, jackson

I am trying to format XML from Kotlin data class and I have a problem with attributes. Question is how to add attribute to one field, trying to format something like this:

```
<ExampleClass>
   <field actionCode="Add">aa</field>
</ExampleClass>
```

By this:

```
data class ExampleClass (
    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true, localName = "actionCode")
    var fieldActionCode: String = "Add",

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "field")
    var field: String = "aa"
)
```

But by doing so attribute goes to wrong place, to Example class:

```
<ExampleClass actionCode="Add">
   <field>aa</field>
</ExampleClass>
```

I use FasterXML Jackson library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attribute goes to **correct** place since you declare `fieldActionCode` as an attribute of ExampleClass, not of its nested element.

Desired output can be achieved like this:

```kotlin
data class ExampleClass (
    @field:JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "field")
    var field: ExampleField = ExampleField()
) {

    data class ExampleField(
        @field:JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true, localName = "actionCode")
        var fieldActionCode: String = "Add",

        @field:JacksonXmlText
        var field: String = "aa"
    )
}

fun main() {
    val mapper = XmlMapper().enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT)
    println(mapper.writeValueAsString(ExampleClass()))
}
```

Produces:

```
<ExampleClass>
  <field actionCode="Add">aa</field>
</ExampleClass>
```